# Expansion of the complex normal distribution around sigma = 0

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, normal-distribution, dirac-delta

I would like to expand the function
$$
f_\sigma(x, x') = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi i \sigma^2}}e^{i\frac{(x-x')^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$
around $\sigma^2\approx 0$. I only know
$$
\lim_{\sigma^2\to 0}f_\sigma(x, x') =\delta(x-x')
$$
So I would expect
$$
f_\sigma(x, x') \approx \delta(x-x') + O(\sigma^2)
$$
How do I find the next term, namely $O(\sigma^2)$ ? Is it even possible?

Comment: Are you sure?  For the real Gaussian the exponent $\to -\infty$ as $\sigma \to 0$ except when $x=x'$.  Not so here.  $e^{-\infty}=0$ but $|e^{i\infty}|=1$.

Comment: Yeap, see https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/. The idea is that for $\sigma\to 0$ the exponential fluctuates a lot, and therefore for any $x\neq x'$ the integral would include as many positive values as negative (provided that the function below the integral sign is regular enough).

Comment: Link didn't help - got nowhere.  However, the integrand does not $\to 0$ for $\sigma \to 0$, so the limit is not a delta function.